# Print inside form using php

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a shout box, although most of the things are simple, I'm stuck with 2 thing. (Printing text inside the shout window and having this form as a popup which can be minimized/maximised)
My code for creating box is

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post"> 
<textarea name="shout"> </textarea> 
<input type="submit" value="Shout out"/>
```

page2.php just writes the text in shout.txt

```
<?php
$fp = fopen("shouts.txt", "a");    // Open the file shouts.txt
fwrite($fp, $_POST['shout']."\n"); // Write the shout
fclose($fp);                       // Close the file
?>
```

and then I need to display latest messages

```
<?php
$shouts = file('shouts.txt'); 
$shouts = array_reverse($shouts); 
$shouts = array_slice ($shouts, 0, 50); 
foreach ($shouts as $item) 
{ 
echo $item."<br/>";  #this should be printed inside shout box/window
}
?>
```

My full HTML is a bigger HTML page and this chunk of code has been inserted in it. By clicking shout it opens page2.php rather it should just remain on the same page.

1. Way to echo latest messages inside shout window
2. Use this form as a chat-popup
3. page2.php is just a script to write to shout.txt, it should not redirect to blank page, maybe giving a target should work

Comment: try `<textarea name="shout"><?php echo $item;?></textarea> `

Comment: Double quotes around `$item`, no quotes around `<br/>`, full stop within double quotes, forward slash in the wrong position. The line `echo "$item."<br/>;` is *very* invalid.

Comment: @jDo corrected, Chetan I did echo "<textarea name='shout'>";
foreach ($shouts as $item)
{
    echo $item;
}
echo "</textarea>"; but this creates 2 widows and doesnt work

Comment: @user1977867 Well, partly fixed but still invalid html. What about reading up on html and php? I wouldn't have spotted the errors if I hadn't done that myself at some point.

Comment: @jDo added the php tags aswell, I am unable to clearly understand what you mean by reading up on html and php.

Comment: @user1977867 My mistake; didn't read the edit properly. By reading up on the topics, I simply meant that there are many guides to PHP and html that allow us to quickly spot syntax errors in our code - it's often much quicker than waiting for someone else to figure it out.